# How to get selected/highlighted text from <textarea> using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, selection, highlight

I have a `<textarea>` which I want to use as a editing panel similar to the ones found in most bulletin boards and forums (even like the one in here). There has to be a 'bold text' button which should bold the currently selected/highlighted text in the `<textarea>`.

How do I do so using javascript.

For example if the following belongs in the `<body>`-

```
<textarea id="txtArea">Some text here.</textarea>
<input type="button" id="btnCmd" onclick="boldthis('txtArea');" value="Bold">
```

How do I complete the javascript code `function boldthis(elementid){}` so I can do
at least collect the selected text in `<textarea id="txtArea">`?

*You may or may not use the example I used to describe your explaination, as long as I understand the logic. Thanks for reading.*