# Getting and setting of a text selection in a textarea

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I want to create a textarea where users can select a part of a text, and I will react according to their selection. So I need to

1) get the start and end positions of the selection text

2) get the position of the focus, if it is in the textarea and there is no selection

It seems that the functions to do so are different from an explorer to another. So could anyone tell me what is the approach to do that in Office Add-in?

I have tried the following 2 ways (ie, select a part of the text in `myTextarea`, click on `button`, and then debug the code), they don't seem to be the right functions.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();
            $('#button').click(showSelection);
        });
    };

    function showSelection() {
        // way 1
        console.log(document.selection); // undefined
        document.getElementById("myTextarea").focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange(); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRange' of undefined
        selectedText = sel.text;
        // way 2 
        console.log(document.getElementById("myTextarea").selectionstart); // undefined
        console.log(document.getElementById("myTextarea").selectionend); // undefined
    }
})();
```

Additionally, it would be great if one could also tell me how to realise the follows by code:

1) select a part of a text, from a start and end positions

2) set the focus at a certain position of the textarea

**Edit 1:**

I just tried `window.getSelection()` within my Excel add-in:

```
function showselection() {
    var a = window.getSelection();
    var b = window.getSelection().toString();
    var c = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
}
```

After selecting a text in the textarea, and clicking on `button`, I debugged step by step: the first line made `a` `a = Selection {anchorNode: null, anchorOffset: 0, focusNode: null, focusOffset: 0, is ...`; the second line returned `""`, the third line got an error `Home.js:19 Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.` It looks like the selection has not been successfully caught...

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mayepu/8/edit?html,js,console,output) without Excel add-in frame, which returns almost same results as above.

Comment: A few questions:
1. What do you mean by "position of the focus"? How is that different from the user's selection?
2. It looks like there's a DOM object with ID "myTextArea": could you clarify what that is?

Comment: 1. when there is no selection, users could still click in the textarea and put the focus, i want to get its position. 2) "myTextArea" is just an `ms-TextField` (I could well use other classes of textarea if they provide getters and setters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JQuery.

For instance, the following two lines get the caret position:

```
function showselection() {
    console.log($('#myTextarea')[0].selectionStart);
    console.log($('#myTextarea')[0].selectionEnd);
}
```

There are some plug-ins:

https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection

http://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/

The second one has several short samples with buttons (where we may lose selection). You could either use their API, or look into their code to see which JQuery functions they call.

Answer (score 1):

If the desired selection is just the selected text in the HTML page (and not the user's selection in Excel/Word), then there are some good [stackoverflow answers about accessing that selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426495/how-to-get-selected-highlighted-text-from-textarea-using-javascript).

Comment: I am quite confused by these answers... It seems that the solutions are different from one explorer to another... I have tried some (as in OP), but not all... Maybe I should try JQuery solutions, because by default Excel add-in uses JQuery?

Comment: It looks like there are consistent ways to access the HTML text selection across all browsers (is that what you mean by "explorer"?). For example, the window.getSelection() API appears to be supported everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I mean "browser"... It will be great if `window.getSelection()` works for all the browsers. I just tried, it could not work property... Could you take a look at my updated OP?

Answer (score 0):

One of the key features of the JavaScript APIs for Office is that they follow an asynchronous model (the code you've written above for showSelection() appears to be synchronous). I'd recommend reading the [Excel](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=word) and [Word](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-programming-overview) JS API overview pages to get a feel for how they work. As an example, here's how you'd get the text from a selection:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var myRange = context.document.getSelection();
    context.load(myRange, 'text');
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        log("Selection contents: " + myRange.text);
    });
})
```

Then for the other specifics of your question please clarify as requested in my comment. Thanks!

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: Thank you for this... I should have clarified that it is mainly for Excel, and the textarea is a part of the Excel add-in. I tried `document.getElementById("myTextarea").getSelection();` it says `getSelection is not a function`...

Comment: I see. So then is your question at all related to the interaction between the HTML/JS and Excel, or is it only about the HTML/JS web page that goes in the task pane?

Comment: It is only about the HTML/JS Excel add-in that goes in the task pane... Sorry that it was not clear in the beginning...